# How to find function definition

Tags: sql-server, functions, database-internals, master-system-database

How can I find the definitions of below system functions in SQL Server:

1. has_access
2. permission_name

I tried with DAC connection but getting below error:

```
Msg 15009, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_helptext, Line 54 [Batch Start Line 118]
The object 'has_access' does not exist in database 'master' or is invalid for this operation.
```

Please let me know if any further details are required. Thanks!

Comment: Although some undocumented internal system objects are stored in the `mssqlsystemresource` database ([which can be attached as a user database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/213494/how-to-locate-resource-system-database-in-ms-sql-server)), I suspect these are implemented in the database engine code. Why are you looking for the source code?

Comment: It's probably a mistake to assume there's a T-SQL definition for these functions.

Comment: @DanGuzman I was trying to create a script for logins and server level permissions from a backup of master database restored as a user database.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Thanks! I didn't know that these functions do not have definitions.

Comment: Have you considered restoring master to a test instance?

Comment: Yes, but I was curious to know if it's possible using this way and was doing some research in this direction.

Comment: SQLPRODDBA where are you seeing these two functions? SSMS does seem to recognize them, not in the completion pop-up, but once fully typed in. But trying to use them results in `'has_access' is not a recognized built-in function name.`. And they aren't found in `SELECT * FROM [master].[sys].[all_objects] ORDER BY [name];`. So far I agree with @DanGuzman 's suspicion that, if they do exist, then they are probably internal / built-in functions.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky you can find these two functions in definitions of sys.server_permissions and sys.server_principals system views.

Answer (score 1):

These two functions appear to be internal / built-in functions given that:

1. they are referenced without a schema-name
2. SSMS color-codes them the same as all other built-in functions

`sys.server_permissions`, on Line #7, has:

```
        p.type, permission_name(p.class, p.type) AS permission_name,
```

`sys.server_principals`, on Line # 18, has:

```
    WHERE has_access('LG', p.id) = 1
```

When the instance is in single-user mode, I can execute the following:

```
USE [mssqlsystemresource];
SELECT PERMISSION_NAME(100, 'COSQ');
-- CONNECT SQL
```

The same statement does not work outside of `mssqlsystemresource`, nor does it work in that DB when prefixed with `sys.` or `dbo.`.

Ergo, no, there is no definition that you will be able to get.